# Mocking calender Build function which take input stream

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test

```
@mock
private MultipartFile multipart;
public int filexyz(Map map,MulitpartFile file){
InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
CalenderBuilder builder = new CalenderBuilder();
calender = builder.build(in);///this  line causing parsing error
}
@Test
public void filexyzTest(){
InputStream in  = new ByteArrayInputStream("2000,1,MONDAY\\n".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
when(multipart.getInputStream().thenReturn(in);
xyz.filexyz(map,multipartFile);
```

}
I am testing the function but it thrwoing error,parsingException
any help`enter code here`

Comment: which library does `CalenderBuilder` belong to?

Comment: It belongs to maven.